# Is it possible to use Emmet in a blank CSS sheet, outside of a selector?

Tags: html, css, emmet

I am currently making my live easier with various custom emmet short forms for code I use a lot. So I tried to make something like the ! in html for CSS so that I can have a * margin reset, comments sectioning my code, media queries etc.

The problem is that for me, emmets validation only allows it to work inside of a selector.. so I would have to type a p{} and the the ! inside that which adds unnecessary work. Do you guys know a way to change the validation?

I went thru all the settings and files I could find, also checked out the documentation.

thx ^^